# Sensitive data on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

Including a sensitive data on the client side.

How can I include the user id or other sensitive data in the client side, and retrieve it after that without allows to the customer to change it in the #clientside?

For example:

```
<li data-user-id="1">name</li>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question

Comment: If you have something you don't want the end user to know, then it shouldn't be sent to the client period. Even if you did accomplish this, what would be the point of sending it to the client if the client can't even use it because it's encrypted? This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Because ,When User want to make something on the app like friend request or something then I can got him with his Id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best choice is to use some encryption like JWT and store the user data in the payload. Don't share the private key on the client side so the token can't be tampered with.

Or after login of the user creates a cookie and saves it in the database alongside the user id. Store the cookie token in the cookies of the user. The user logs in with the cookie and you know which user it is by the cookie. If they change the cookie token then it won't match the ones in the database.

Comment: so the best way is to use api with JWT Thank you

Comment: Yes I use JWT too on my .NET Core API. It works like a charm.